# How to only view a subset of columns in pandas head?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am using pandas in jupyter notebook and I quite like the way dataframes are displayed. I have 80 columns of data and I want to show the general setup of my data in my thesis. I.e., I want to show the index, and some column names. I like that pandas does not display all columns, but instead shows some of the first, then some dots (...) and then some of the last column. However, this way of displaying is still wider than my screen so it is hard to copy this to my thesis. The screenshot below shows what I have:
[image]

What I would like is to show a smaller amount of columns, while still having those dots (...) so it fits on my page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to limit the no. of columns using `pd.options.display.max_columns`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455722/pandas-is-there-a-max-size-max-no-of-columns-max-rows

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163830/ipython-notebook-pandas-max-allowable-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the max number of columns to display:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 5)

pd.DataFrame(np.eye(10).head())
```

Output:

```
     0    1  ...    8    9
0  1.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  ...  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: @Pygirl Sure, no worries. And I agree with closing this as a duplicate, added my close vote

Answer (score 6):

To view a subset of columns you should filter that using .loc:

```
df.loc[:,['col1', 'col3']].head()
```

- df => your data frame
- col1 and col2 => the columns desired